# Benchmark linux server?

Tags: linux, debian, benchmark

I want to benchmark some servers but i have never done it before. Could someone suggest me some script or give me some guidelines for testing of basic, usual web server. What are the most important parameters etc.

What application/way of testing you suggest?

Servers that i want to test are mostly apache+php+mysql, Debian as OS and host multiple domains with applications like wordpress and/or similar web CMS applications.

Comment: @dmourati, could you tell me why this question is not good?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I simply changed the spelling of benchmark.

Comment: You need to run stress tests?

Comment: @ghm1014 not exactly, i actually need just to measure processor power and if possible specifically in doing apache-php-mysql page rendering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's little bit strange to answer question that i asked. However, so far, simplest to use and with numerous different tests was [phoronix-test-suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/)

I think there was no need for any other after this.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two scripts you may find useful:

[httperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/)

[ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)

Comment: thank you, will look into that, i used jakarta too but that was not what i wanted. I needed processor power test..